# SQL Server query + joining results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT recipientid AS ID,
COUNT(*) AS Recieved FROM Inbox
GROUP BY recipientid

UNION

SELECT SenderId,
COUNT(*) AS [Sent] FROM Inbox
GROUP BY SenderId
```

**The output:**

```
RecipientID  Recieved

001             3
001             4
002             4
002             2
003            18
003            55
```

How can I rewrite is such a way that it displays like this:

```
RecipientID  Recieved  Sent

001             3       4
002             4       2
003            18       55
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join the subqueries:

```
select a.ID,Received,Sent
from(
  SELECT recipientid AS ID,
  COUNT(*) AS Recieved FROM Inbox
  GROUP BY recipientid
)a
full outer join(
  SELECT SenderId as ID,
  COUNT(*) AS [Sent] FROM Inbox
  GROUP BY SenderId
)b
on (a.ID = b.ID)
order by a.ID;
```

Note that this grabs all of the `sent` and `received` values for any recipients or senders. If you only want results for `ID`s belonging to recipients and senders, then do an `inner join`.

Comment: You want that to be a full outer join, not an inner join, otherwise you'll only get recipients who have both sent and received messages.

Comment: @MattW - Good call (although that wasn't completely clear from the question). Lemme edit...

Comment: And ID is ambiguous in the first select line.

Comment: ..and probably in the order by line, too :D

Comment: @KekuSemau - D'oh! I've been spoiled by PostgreSQL where you can do things like `order by 1,2` and `group by 1,2`, etc, so I tend to fudge over and abstract that away when I really shouldn't.

Comment: Since it is a full outer join, you should also coalesce the id (since `a.ID` might be null).

Comment: @ChrisShaffer - Well, now we're getting into territory where the OP can alter the query to his/her tastes. But yes, if I were using this query in a report or data pull for my boss, I'd either include `b.ID` as well or consider using a `coalesce` for `ID`s to something like `"N/A"`.

Comment: @JackManey - I did vote this answer up, I just think it is important for the op and anyone who stumbles on your answer in the future to get a correct answer; Your answer technically is not correct currently since it will include rows with `NULL` for the ID; The correct first column would be `COALESCE(a.ID, b.ID) AS ID`, so every row has an ID... I don't consider that a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a `source` column to your query and do a simple pivot

```
select ID, 
       max (case when source=1 then Cnt else 0 end) as Received,
       max (case when source=2 then Cnt else 0 end) as Sent
from (
  SELECT 1 as Source, 
         recipientid AS ID,
         COUNT(*) AS Cnt 
  FROM Inbox
  GROUP BY recipientid
  UNION
  SELECT 2 as Source, 
         SenderId,
         COUNT(*)  
  FROM Inbox
  GROUP BY SenderId
  ) x
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I might suggest using `SUM` instead of `MAX`.

Comment: I thought about it and this is usually what I do (SUM instead of MAX), but the inner two queries are grouped anyway so it is safe... But it's clearer maybe... Also, I don't even need the inner group by then

Answer (score 0):

If it's Postgres, MS SQL or others that support CTEs -

```
With Both as
(
SELECT
  recipientid AS ID,
  Count(*) AS Recieved,
  0 as [Sent] 
FROM Inbox
GROUP BY recipientid
UNION
SELECT
  SenderId as ID,
  0 as Recieved,
  Count(*) AS [Sent]
FROM Inbox
GROUP BY SenderId
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Sum(Received) as [Received],
  Sum(Sent) as [Sent]
FROM BOTH
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `users` table with the IDs, you could do something like:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    COUNT(sent.senderid) AS sent,
    COUNT(received.recipientid) AS received
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN inbox AS sent ON sent.senderid = users.id
    LEFT JOIN inbox AS received ON received.recipientid = users.id
GROUP BY sent.senderid, received.recipientid
ORDER BY users.id;
```